# Spark throwing FileNotFoundException when overwriting dataframe on S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have partitioned parquet files stored on two locations on S3 in the same bucket:

```
path1: s3n://bucket/a/
path2: s3n://bucket/b/
```

The data has the same structure. I want to read the files from the first location and aggregate them to the second location using spark sql. Here is the code snippet:

```
val df1 = sql.read.parquet(path1)
val df2 = sql.read.parquet(path2)

val df = df1.unionAll(df2)

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path1)
```

When I run this piece of code I get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 
s3n://a/part-r-00001-file.gz.parquet
```

I'm using spark 1.6.1 and scala 2.11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a direct solution to this problem so I used a workaround:

```
val df2 = sql.read.parquet(path2)
df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(path1)

val df1 = sql.read.parquet(path1)
df1.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above case as both the read and write paths are same the consistency model becomes eventual consistency. 
To give an example in your code data is read from same path1 and the final data is also to path1, it reads the data initially but as spark starts writing data the data being read is removed hence giving `java.io.FileNotFound` exception.
So if possible you should use different path for writing the final output.

This kind of read write if even considered as error in spark sql, when you read a dataframe from a table and write to that same table an error is thrown by spark, telling read and write to same location not allowed.

Comment: @AbdulMalik I believe "you should use a different path for writing the final output" to be a valid answer. I don't know whether it's correct because I'm in review and can't see the original question. But it's not an invalid answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### recommend to use spark.yarn.stagingDir

```
    private fun read(
        target: String,
        extension: Extension,
        repartition: Int? = 1,
    ): Dataset<Row> {
        return SparkUtil.make()
            .read()
            .format(extension.name)
            .load(target)
            .repartition(repartition!!)
    }

    private fun merge(
        target: String,
        extension: Extension,
        repartition: Int? = 1,
    ) {
        val ds = read(target, extension, repartition)

        val dir = SparkUtil.conf("spark.yarn.stagingDir") // stagingDir
        val id = SparkUtil.id() // applicationId
        val temp = "$dir/$id"

        ds.write()
            .format(extension.name)
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .save(temp)

        read(temp, extension, repartition)
            .write()
            .format(extension.name)
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .save(target)
    }
```